# RSS channel feed not showing feed data

Tags: android

actually in my app i want to do rss parsing. but when i parse data ts not giving me the response.
i have some problem with rss parser in my app.
i have put all my code and my rss data.
i tried many times but it will not giving me any data

### and return listsize=0

my RSS channel data

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="/css/ticketekCore.css" ?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="/css/ticketekPageLayouts.css" ?>
    <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
            <title>Ticketek Event Listing</title>
            <link>http://www.ticketek.com.au/</link>
            <description>Ticketek Event Listing</description>   
            <language>en-au</language>          
    <item>
        <title><![CDATA[The 2016 Cranston Cup Theatresports Grand Final]]></title>
        <link>http://premier.ticketek.com.au/shows/show.aspx?sh=TSCRANST16</link>
        <guid isPermaLink="true">http://premier.ticketek.com.au/shows/show.aspx?sh=TSCRANST16</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[
    <div class=" clearfix">
      <div class="resultContainer">
        <div class="contentImage">
          <a href="/shows/show.aspx?sh=TSCRANST16"><img src="//d35kvm5iuwjt9t.cloudfront.net/dbimages/sfx161301.jpg" style="width:61px;height:61px;" alt="The 2016 Cranston Cup Theatresports Grand Final" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="contentEvent">
          <h6>
            <a href="/shows/show.aspx?sh=TSCRANST16">The 2016 Cranston Cup Theatresports Grand Final</a>
          </h6>
        </div>
            <div class="contentEventAndDate clearfix">
              <div class="contentLocation">
                 <strong>Enmore Theatre</strong><br />
                  NSW/ACT
              </div>
              <div class="contentDate"> Sun 27 Nov 2016 </div>
              <div class="resultBuyNow">
                <a class="yellowGradientButton" href="/shows/show.aspx?sh=TSCRANST16&amp;v=NMO">Get Tickets</a>
              </div>
            </div>

      </div>
    </div>
        ]]></description>
    </item>
```

---

```
My java code:
Fragment.java
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pDialog = (RelativeLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.progressBarHolder);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                String weburl = RssFragment.this.getArguments().getString(MainActivity.DATA);
                URL rssUrl = new URL(weburl);
                SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
                RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
                myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
                InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
                myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

                myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();            
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            ListView listview = (ListView) ll.findViewById(R.id.list);

            if (myRssFeed != null) {

            int size =  myRssFeed.getList().size();
                Log.d("listsize", String.valueOf(size));

                MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(mAct, R.layout.fragment_rss_row, myRssFeed.getList());
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mAct,
                                RssDetailActivity.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("keyTitle", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getTitle());
                        bundle.putString("keyDescription", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getDescription());
                        bundle.putString("keyLink", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getLink());
                        bundle.putString("keyPubdate", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getPubdate());
                        bundle.putString("keyThumbnail", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getThumburl());
                        bundle.putString("keyVideo", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getVideourl());
                        bundle.putString("keyAudio", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getAudiourl());
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                String url = RssFragment.this.getArguments().getString(MainActivity.DATA);
                String message = null;
                if (!url.startsWith("http"))
                    message = "Debug info: '" + url + "' is most likely not a valid RSS url. Make sure the url entered in your configuration starts with 'http' and verify if it's valid XML using https://validator.w3.org/feed/";
                Helper.noConnection(mAct, true, message);
            }

            if (pDialog.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                pDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //feedListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Helper.revealView(listview,ll);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

---

```
my RSShandler class

package com.sherdle.universal.rss;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.text.Html;

/**
 *  This class is used to help us get the right information from the data from the feed.
 */

public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private State currentState = State.unknown;

    private RSSFeed feed;
    private RSSItem item;

    private boolean itemFound = false;

    private StringBuilder tagContent;

    public RSSHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        feed = new RSSFeed();
        item = new RSSItem();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName, final Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {
        currentState = State.unknown;
        tagContent = new StringBuilder();


        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item") || localName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {
            itemFound = true;
            item = new RSSItem();
            currentState = State.unknown;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            currentState = State.title;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("description") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded")) {
            currentState = State.description;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("link") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("origLink")) {
            currentState = State.link;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubdate") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("published")) {
            currentState = State.pubdate;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")) {
            currentState = State.media;    
            String attrValue = attributes.getValue("url");
            item.setThumburl(attrValue);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("media:content")){
            currentState = State.media;   
            String attrValue = attributes.getValue("url");
            if (attributes.getValue("type") == null || attributes == null){
                return;
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("image")){
                item.setThumburl(attrValue);
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("video")){ 
                item.setVideourl(attrValue);
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("audio")){ 
                item.setAudiourl(attrValue);
            } 
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure")){
            currentState = State.media;   
            String attrValue = attributes.getValue("url");
            if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("image")){
                item.setThumburl(attrValue);
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("video")){ 
                item.setVideourl(attrValue);
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("audio")){ 
                item.setAudiourl(attrValue);
            } 
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(final String uri, final String localName, 
            final String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item") || localName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {
            feed.addItem(item);
        }
        if (itemFound == true) {
            // "item" tag found, it's item's parameter
            switch (currentState) {
                case title:
                    String title = Html.fromHtml(tagContent.toString().trim()).toString();
                    item.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(tagContent.toString().trim()).toString());
                    break;
                case description:
                    String description = tagContent.toString();
                    item.setDescription(tagContent.toString());                   
                    //if thumburl not already set
                    if (item.getThumburl() == null || item.getThumburl() == ""){
                        String html = tagContent.toString();
                        org.jsoup.nodes.Document docHtml = Jsoup
                        .parse(html);
                        Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");
                        String source = imgEle.attr("src");
                        item.setThumburl(source);
                    }
                    break;
                case link:
                    String link =tagContent.toString();
                    item.setLink(tagContent.toString());
                    break;
                case pubdate:
                    String pubdate =tagContent.toString();
                    item.setPubdate(tagContent.toString());
                    break;
                case media:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            // not "item" tag found, it's feed's parameter
            switch (currentState) {
                case title:
                    feed.setTitle(tagContent.toString());
                    break;
                case description:
                    feed.setDescription(tagContent.toString());
                    break;
                case link:
                    feed.setLink(tagContent.toString());
                    break;
                case pubdate:
                    feed.setPubdate(tagContent.toString());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(final char[] ch, final int start, final int length) 
            throws SAXException {
        tagContent.append(ch, start, length);
    }
    public RSSFeed getFeed() {
        return feed;
    }
        public enum State {
        unknown, title, description, link, pubdate, media
    }
}
```